# btrace Invalid path 9116 specified: 2/No such file or directory

Tags: btrace

i use btrace in linux，Remind me：
Invalid path 9116 specified: 2/No such file or directory
my exec command：btrace 9116 AllMethods.java
my home path is ok， i got Pid by jps，   btrace version is 1.3.8.3

Answer (score 2):

This looks suspicious. Please, make sure that you don't have the 'other' [btrace tool](https://linux.die.net/man/8/btrace) in path.

Comment: yes,I sure. if i use 'my btrace path'/btrace this command,i can run btrarce.but, this operation is blocked.

Comment: What is the output of `btrace --help` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute "which btrace", make sure this btrace is your want btrace